# Microphone not working on Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBookPro10,2

Tags: alsa, microphone

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook Pro Retina `MacBookPro10,2` and the microphone does not work at all.

It has worked in 13.04 and 13.10 but now after a clean install, no luck.

I ran this script to get some more info

`wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`

which uploaded the info to http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=140db56ebf8372fc1ee6026a8164c610264d8165

I'm not sure what I'm looking for though.

I've tried reinstalling ALSA and also installing PulseAudio with no luck.

The speakers are working just fine.

Here is a screenshot of `alsamixer`. I've tried switching to Internal Mic 1 with no luck.

[image: alsamixer]

I'm looking forward to any help. I'm really struggling without a microphone as I work from home and do a lot of VoIP calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I finally found it. Amazing how quickly that happens after you ask a question.

I added the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

`options snd-hda-intel model=mbp101`

Credit goes to fooblahblah https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=144255&p=4

So happy right now.