# Macbook Pro's (10.2) built-In microphone not detected on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, microphone, macbook-pro

While attempting to configure my Macbook Pro's built-in webcam microphone for Mumble, I noticed that the microphone was not detected.

Opening VLC, I attempted to capture the built-in webcam in an attempt to see if it would detect the microphone, which it did not. (The webcam worked out of the box flawlessly.)

A [previous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482626/microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbookpro10-2) AskUbuntu question covered this issue, suggesting that the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp101
```

to be added to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

After restarting, this had no noticeable effect. Attempting `mbp102` yielded no effect as well.