# My microphone is not working in Mac book pro 17 after ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, macbook, microphone

My microphone is not working in Mac bookpro 17(2010) after ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04.

Sound settings Input shows microphone build-in Audio. but no input level signal.

BTW, my Mac bookpro 13(2009)'s build-in microphone is working in Ubuntu 16.04.

How to fix it? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

With my old **macbook 2,1** (Libreboot + Elementary OS Loki (based on Ubuntu 16.04)) the solution to getting the microphone working was installing `pavucontrol` and on the `Input Devices` tab choosing `Microphone (unplugged)` instead of `Line In (plugged in)`. In fact I have nothing plugged in or unplugged.

Comment: Working solution for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on Macbook Pro 17" Early 2011. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook Pro Core i5 2.5 13" Retina 2012 and was in the same position, sound worked fine but no microphone.

Adding the following line to the bottom of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` worked for me:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp101
```

as per [Microphone not working on Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBookPro10,2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482626/microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbookpro10-2)

I think I had done this in the past but a clean install of Xenial had removed the line, perhaps the same happened when you upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

The downvoted answer from above works on a 2009 MacBook Pro, with Ubuntu 20.04.  Conversely, only the microphone would be detected, not the line input.

"Adding the following line to the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf worked for me:

options snd-hda-intel model=mbp101"

Thank you @nicja