# Microphone problems Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, macbook, microphone, macbook-pro

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. My microphone is not working. My speakers are working though. I got a Macbook Pro from late 2011. Someone got any tips how to fix this? I played with the audio settings but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBook Pro Core i5 2.5 13" Retina 2012 and was in the same position, sound worked fine but no microphone.

Adding the following line to the bottom of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` worked for me:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp101
```

as per [Microphone not working on Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBookPro10,2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482626/microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbookpro10-2)

I think I had done this in the past but a clean install of Xenial had removed the line.

After a reboot the mic was working again!